# Adding Spfx Web Parts to Modern site Pages using PNP CSOM in Azure AD Apps

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, modern-pages, pnp-provision, azureadapps

I had Create a web application with Azure AD authentication using Azure AD Application. I had granted all permission  for  SharePoint Online,Graph Api and Active Directory to the App for provisioning Site collections(creation and Deletion) which is working fine.

Now i am trying to add Spfx Web part to a  Modern page. I followed the Msdn article [Customizing Modern site pages](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-pages) which is working fine with user Context.

But in my web application i am accessing the site collections through tenant Context(`https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com`) using  access tokens from the Azure AD App.
 Now i want to know how to add spfx webpart to  modern page of a specific site collection using the tenant context

Below is the code that i am trying to add the spfx webpart to modern pages using Tenant context.

```
 var tenant = new Tenant(spcontext);
                spcontext.Load(tenant);
                spcontext.ExecuteQuery();
                var site = tenant.GetSiteByUrl(webUrl);
                spcontext.Load(site);
                spcontext.Load(site.RootWeb);
                spcontext.ExecuteQuery();
                string pageName = "mypage.aspx";
                ClientSidePage page = ClientSidePage.Load(spcontext, pageName);
                var components = page.AvailableClientSideComponents();
                string wpName = "Intranet Manager";
                List<string> componentsnames = components.Select(k => k.Name).ToList();
                var webPartToAdd = components.Where(wp => wp.ComponentType == 1 && wp.Name == wpName).FirstOrDefault();
                if (webPartToAdd != null)
                {
                    ClientSideWebPart clientWp = new ClientSideWebPart(webPartToAdd) { Order = -1 };
                    page.AddControl(clientWp);
                }
                page.Save(pageName);
                spcontext.ExecuteQuery();
```

I am getting the below error

```
"Site https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com does not have a sitepages library and therefore this page can't be a client side page.
```

Since I am using the tenant context. Can anyone guide me in right way?

**Update:**

Methods using for getting the Access token in the MVC Web Application. Here I am passing  `https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com` as the parameter for the method **GetSharePointContext**

```
public ClientContext GetSharePointContext(string SiteUrl)
{
    ClientContext spContext = null;
    try
    {
        Task<string> result = Task.Run<string>(() => GetAccessToken(SiteUrl));
        result.Wait();
        if (result != null)
        {
            spContext = TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithAccessToken(SiteUrl, result.Result);
        }

    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {

    }
    return spContext;
}


  public async Task<string> GetAccessToken(string siteurl)
        {
            AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = null;
            string signedInUserID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
            string tenantID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;
            string userObjectID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;
            // get a token for the Graph without triggering any user interaction (from the cache, via multi-resource refresh token, etc)
            ClientCredential clientcred = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
            try
            {
                Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantID, new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserID));
                authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(siteurl, clientcred, new UserIdentifier(userObjectID, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));
                return authenticationResult.AccessToken;
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the samples in the articles below, when creating a new client-side page, finally save the page to the site pages library.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-pages

And there is no sitepages library in the site https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com, it will throw the error.

So we should use the user context not the tenant context.

Comment: If it is user context it was working fine. But I want to get the context to the specific site collection from the tenant context since we are using the Azure AD App

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Amy, you need to switch the context to a site collection context from the tenant context.

The sharepoint admin site doesn't have the site pages library, so its throwing that error.

You can make use of PnP's `clone` method to "take over" the security context of existing client context instance as below:

Modify your code as below:

```
var tenant = new Tenant(spcontext);
spcontext.Load(tenant);
spcontext.ExecuteQuery();
var site = tenant.GetSiteByUrl(webUrl);
spcontext.Load(site);
spcontext.Load(site.RootWeb);
spcontext.ExecuteQuery();

using (ClientContext newSiteContext = spcontext.Clone(webUrl))
{
    string pageName = "mypage.aspx";
    ClientSidePage page = ClientSidePage.Load(newSiteContext, pageName);
    var components = page.AvailableClientSideComponents();
    string wpName = "Intranet Manager";
    List<string> componentsnames = components.Select(k => k.Name).ToList();
    var webPartToAdd = components.Where(wp => wp.ComponentType == 1 && wp.Name == wpName).FirstOrDefault();
    if (webPartToAdd != null)
    {
        ClientSideWebPart clientWp = new ClientSideWebPart(webPartToAdd) { Order = -1 };
        page.AddControl(clientWp);
    }
    page.Save(pageName);
    newSiteContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Comment: I am Getting the error "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized." at the line ClientSidePage page = ClientSidePage.Load(newSiteContext, pageName);

Comment: If it tenant context created with user credentials, the clone was working fine. If the context is created with Access token from the Azure AD app I am getting the above 401 error.

Comment: Could be something wrong with Azure AD configuration/permission ? Since it works with User credentials, looks to be some config issue

Comment: With the same Azure AD configuration, I am able to create Site collections, lists etc.. The only issue I am not able to clone the context

Comment: ok but why are you loading tenant context in the first place ? why not directly load site collection context ?

Comment: I am getting the context by passing  the SharePoint tenant URL using  the access tokens and then I am using the  tenant context to provision  CRUD operation on the Site Collections

Comment: Updated the question with the methods that I am using for getting the access token and Sharepoint tenant context

Comment: If you have any sample code to get the site collection Context directly using Access token, please provide or any reference link

Comment: hey @TARUN, can you try `using (ClientContext newSiteContext = new ClientContext(webUrl))` and check ?

Comment: Will try and update you..

Comment: Now we are getting the error The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.